# How to add a menu with submenues in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to add a menu with submenues in Wordpress, but so far my attempts don't seem to work:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'practice_areas', 11, 3 );

function practice_areas( $items, $args ) {
    $items .= '<ul><a href="'. addslashes("#") . '">Practice Areas</a>';
    $items .= '<li><a href="'. addslashes("#") . '">Practice Areas</a></li>';
    $items .= '</ul>';
    return $items;
}
```

How can I go about adding a menue with submenues?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: you can add menus with levels in admin panel. Go to Appearance -> Menus, create Links you want and just drag and drop them to create a sub-level

Comment: I need to do it programatically

Comment: Why? I can't think of any reason why...

Comment: Sometimes you need to add via code: much more efficient, more maintainable, you could iterate when there's a lot of menus to add, etc, etc @yzoja. Think of something like a login, logout, signup menu. You could just add via a child theme, and never do it again.

Comment: But if that's not registered in that case in "Menu" area, then you could just use your own function that will create all the HTML for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the code this way to find it working.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'practice_areas', 11, 3 );

function practice_areas( $items, $args ) {
    $items .= '<li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25"><a href="http://test-main-menu">Test main menu</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#test-submenu">Test submenu</a></li>
</ul>
</li>';
    return $items;
}
```